# Subtract fixed number of days from date column using awk and add it to new column

Tags: csv, date, awk

Let's assume that we have a file with the values as seen bellow:

```
% head test.csv
20220601,A,B,1
20220530,A,B,1
```

And we want to add two new columns, one with the date minus 1 day and one with minus 7 days, resulting the following:

```
% head new_test.csv
20220601,A,B,20220525,20220531,1
20220530,A,B,20220523,20220529,1
```

The awk that was used to produce the above is:

`% awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} { a="date -d \"$(date -d \""$1"\") -7 days\" +'%Y%m%d'"; a | getline st ; close(a) ;b="date -d \"$(date -d \""$1"\") -1 days\" +'%Y%m%d'"; b | getline cb ; close(b) ;print $1","$2","$3","st","cb","$4}' test.csv > new_test.csv`

But after applying the above in a large file with more than 100K lines it runs for 20 minutes, is there any way to optimize the awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using function calls, it is faster than calling the .

```
awk -F, '
    function cmd1(date){
        a="date -d \"$(date -d \""date"\") -1days\" +'%Y%m%d'"
        a | getline st
        return st
        close(a)
    }
    function cmd2(date){
        b="date -d \"$(date -d \""date"\") -7days\" +'%Y%m%d'"
        b | getline cm
        return cm
        close(b)
    }
    {
        $5=cmd1($1)
        $6=cmd2($1)
        print $1","$2","$3","$5","$6","$4
    }' OFS=, test > newFileTest
```

I executed this against a file with 20000 records in seconds, compared to the original awk which took around 5 minutes.

Comment: Function calls will make the code more concise, but not faster. It's still spawning a subshell for every call to `date` either way. As written for an invalid date your code will quietly set `st` or `cm` to the output of `date` for the last valid date, you may want to guard against that, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline, and both of those plus `a` and `b` should be function-local instead of global variables (e.g. `function cmd1(date,   a,st)`).

Answer (score 4):

One `GNU awk` approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","
        secs_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24
      }
      { dt = mktime( substr($1,1,4) " " substr($1,5,2) " " substr($1,7,2) " 12 0 0" )
        dt1 = strftime("%Y%m%d",dt -  secs_in_day      )
        dt7 = strftime("%Y%m%d",dt - (secs_in_day * 7) )
        print $1,$2,$3,dt7,dt1,$4
      }
' test.csv
```

This generates:

```
20220601,A,B,20220525,20220531,1
20220530,A,B,20220523,20220529,1
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `GNU awk` for the `mktime()` and `strftime()` functions; see [GNU awk time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) for more details
- other flavors of `awk` may have similar functions, ymmv

Comment: sure, made the change from 0 to 12